# How to create Calendar table with year and week number in Power Query M?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need help with Power Query in Power BI. I was given a dataset where only year and week number is mentioned. I need to create a calendar table with: year, week number.
For example, I have 2022, 2023 years and for each year there would be 52 weeks entries. I tried M language, but didn't find any solution. Can't create calendar table on the basis of my dataset, because there are not each week mentioned. Can you please suggest me a solution.

Comment: What does your `yr-wknum` table look like? What would your `calendar table` look like? What is your week numbering convention (there are several, and it makes a big difference).

Answer (score 1):

There are various conventions used for week numbering so you will need to determine which one is used in the dataset. For example below, it is set for Monday. If week numbering always starts on 1st January then you'll need to tweak the below.

```
let
  DateStart = #date(2022, 1, 1),
  DateEnd = #date(2023, 12, 31),
  WeekStart = Day.Monday,

  Dates = List.Dates(DateStart, Duration.Days( DateEnd - DateStart )+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
  Source = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.RenameColumns(Table.FromList(Dates, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),{{"Column1", "Date"}}),{{"Date", type date}}),
  #"Add Year" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each Date.Year([Date]), Int32.Type),
  #"Add MonthNum" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Year", "MonthNum", each Date.Month([Date]), Int64.Type),
  #"Add Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add MonthNum", "Month", each Date.ToText([Date], [Format="MMMM"]), type text),
  #"Add Month short" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Month", "Month short", each Date.ToText([Date], [Format="MMM"]), type text),
  #"Add WeekNum" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Month short", "WeekNum", each Date.WeekOfYear([Date], WeekStart), Int64.Type),
  #"Add Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add WeekNum", "Week", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date], WeekStart), type date),
  #"Marked key columns" = Table.AddKey(#"Add Week", {"Date"}, false)
in
  #"Marked key columns"
```

---

If you just need Year and Week (ie not a Calendar table) then:

**PowerQuery**

```
let
  Source = Table.FromList({2022..2023}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Year"}),
  #"Add Weeknum" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "WeekNum", each {1..52}),
  #"Expanded WeekNum" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Weeknum", "WeekNum"),
  #"Add Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded WeekNum", "Week", each "Week " & Number.ToText([WeekNum]))
in
  #"Add Week"
```

**DAX**

```
Dim YearWeek = 
  var minY = 2022 // MIN('YourTable'[Year])
  var maxY = 2023 // MAX('YourTable'[Year])

  return CROSSJOIN(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(minY, maxY), "Year", [Value]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1, 52), "Week", "Week " & [Value], "WeekNum", [Value])
  )
```

Comment: I've added a second part to the answer for a simplified table of just Year, Week, WeekNum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have each week or day in your data. you just need the start date and the end date. You can also do it in DAX, so the contents of the table are dynamic:

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
   CALENDAR(MINX('FactTable',[Date]),MAXX('FactTable',[Date]),
   "Year",YEAR([Date]),
   "MonthNumber",MONTH([Date]),
   "WeekOfYear", WEEK([Date])
)
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any dates in my fact table, only Week numbers  (Week 1, Week 2...) and year (2021, 2022...), no start or end date.

Answer (score 0):

Below Pasted code will help you to create power query table through start date

```
#date(2021, 1, 1) meta [IsParameterQuery = true, IsParameterQueryRequired = true, Type = type date]

Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())



let
  Source = Table.FromList(List.Dates(StartDate,Duration.Days(EndDate - StartDate)+ 1,#duration(1,0,0,0)), Splitter.SplitByNothing(),type table[Date=Date.Type]),
  #"Sorted rows" = Table.Sort(Source, {{"Date", Order.Descending}}),
  #"Insert Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted rows", "Year", each Date.Year([Date]),type number),
  #"Add Date Default" = Table.AddColumn(#"Insert Year", "Add Year Default", each if Date.Year([Date]) = Date.Year( DateTime.LocalNow()) then "Current" else [Year] , type text),
  #"Name of Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Date Default", "Day name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([Date]), type text),
  #"Month Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Name of Day", "Year Month", each Date.ToText([Date], "MMM-yy"),type text),
  #"Month Int" = Table.AddColumn(#"Month Year", "Monthint", each Date.Month([Date]),type number),
  #"Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Month Int", "Month Name", each 
Date.MonthName([Date], "en-EN"),type text),
  #"Month Short" = Table.AddColumn(#"Month Name", "Month Short", each Date.ToText([Date], "MMM", "En-us"),type text),
  #"Add Month Default Logic" = Table.AddColumn(#"Month Short", "Add Month Default", each if Date.Month([Date]) =  Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()) then "Current" else [Month Name],type text),
  #"Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Month Default Logic", "Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth([Date]),type date),
  #"End of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Start of Month", "End of Date", each Date.EndOfMonth([Date]),type date),
  #"Days in Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"End of Month", "Days in Month", each Date.DaysInMonth([Date]),Int64.Type),
  #"Start of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Days in Month", "Start of Week", each Date.StartOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday),type text),
  #"End of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Start of Week", "End of Week", each Date.EndOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday),type date),
  #"Day of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"End of Week", "Day of Week", each Date.DayOfWeek( [Date], Day.Monday ), Int64.Type),
  #"Day of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Day of Week", "Day of Month", each Date.Day([Date]), Int64.Type),
  #"Day of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Day of Month", "Day of Year", each Date.DayOfYear( [Date] ), Int64.Type),
  #"Day Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Day of Year", "Day offset", each Number.From(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) - [Date]),Int64.Type),
  #"Week Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Day Offset", "Week Offset", each Duration.Days( Date.StartOfWeek( [Date], Day.Monday ) - Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(  DateTime.LocalNow(), Day.Monday ))) / 7 , Int64.Type ),
  #"Monthly Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Week Offset", "Monthly Offset", each ( [Year] - Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())) * 12 + ( Date.Month([Date])  - Date.Month( DateTime.LocalNow())),Int64.Type),
  #"Quarter Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Monthly Offset", "Quarter Offset", each ( [Year] - Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) ) * 4 + Date.QuarterOfYear( [Date] ) - Date.QuarterOfYear( DateTime.LocalNow()),Int64.Type),
  #"Yearly Offset" = Table.AddColumn(#"Quarter Offset", "Year Offset", each [Year] - Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),Int64.Type),
  IsWeekend = Table.AddColumn(#"Yearly Offset", "IsWeekend", each if Date.DayOfWeek( [Date] ) >= 5 then 1 else 0,Int64.Type)
in
  IsWeekend
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick answer would be : use calendarauto()

1/ Go to Table view in power bi (not in power query)

- Create a new table :
- `Calendar = CalendarAuto()`
- This will add a calendar, using the first and last day it finds in your dataset

2/ in this new table,

- And a new column
- `week_num = WEEKNUM(Calendar[Date])`

3/ Link this table in the model view (between your fact table and this new table, using the date column).

That's it.

If you prefer do it in power query, the previous answer are correct

Comment: The problem is I don't have any dates, only Week Number and Year, so it won't work, unfortunately

Comment: You can create a column "year-weeknbr" on both table, then join these 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your weeks are numbered according to the `ISO 8601` standard and

if your data table looks like:
[image]

And you want a result table like:
[image]

I suggest you write a custom function to convert a Year and Weeknumber to the appropriate week of individual dates.  Name this `**fnDateFromISOweeknum**`

```
(yr as number, weeknum as number)=>

let 
    week1 = Date.StartOfWeek(#date(yr,1,4),Day.Monday),
    weekDates = List.Dates(Date.AddDays(week1, (weeknum-1)*7),7,#duration(1,0,0,0))
in 
    weekDates
```

You can then use this code to generate a table:

```
let

//Generate sample table with 
// yr = 2022, 2023 and Weeks 1 to 52
    Source = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.Repeat({2022},52) & List.Repeat({2023},52)} &
        {{1..52} & {1..52}},
        type table[Year=Int64.Type, Weeknum=Int64.Type]),

    #"Add Weekdates" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"WeekDates", each fnDateFromISOweeknum([Year],[Weeknum]), type {date}),
    #"Expanded WeekDates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Weekdates", "WeekDates")
in
    #"Expanded WeekDates"
```

Don't forget that some years will have 53 weeks, according to this standard.

If your weeknumbers are generated according to some other convention, one merely needs to change the custom function to accomodate.